# Java Sudoku Solver Output

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with my Sudoku Solver that I need to make, what I am supposed to do is to create a program which checks to see if the inputted Sudoku puzzle is correct or not. I have the code which checks to see if each row, column, and "minibox" working. My only problem now is to print out the puzzle. This is what I have so far:

```
public String printGrid(int size, int[][] puzzle){
    double temp = Math.sqrt(size);

    for(int row = 0; row < size; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < size; column++){
            System.out.print(puzzle[row][column]);

            if(column == temp - 1) {
                System.out.print("|");   
            }

            if(row == temp - 1){
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    System.out.print("-\t");
                }
            }

            if(column == size - 1) {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Correct!";
}
```

As an example size will be 4 and the inputted sudoku will be:

```
 1 2 3 4
 4 3 2 1 
 3 4 1 2
 2 1 4 3
```

My output is to look like this:

```
 1 2 | 3 4
 4 3 | 2 1
 ----+----
 3 4 | 1 2
 2 1 | 4 3
```

My current code however gives an ArrayOutOfBounds error and outputs this:

```
 -  2-  -   -   -   1-  -   -   -   4|121|43
```

I'm completely lost in how to write this method to output, can anyone shed some light on this for me? (Also ignore the fact that all sudokus return "Correct!" I should be able to figure that out myself.)

Comment: where does it give that `Exception`? I mean, which line?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Which is this line:
System.out.print(puzzle[row][column]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 4 problems that I see right away:

1. You don't print a newline at the end of your outer (`row`) loop
2. The `if(row == temp - 1)` loop should be in the outer loop only (you want to do it on it's own row, not each time in the column
3. `column == temp-1` etc. will only work for the 2x2 case, it should be `column > 0 && column % temp == 0`
4. Don't ever ever modify a `for` loop variable inside the loop, that will confuse everything and usually cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, as happens here.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(column == size - 1) {
    column = 0;
    row++;
}
```

Using the above `if-statement`, you are not letting the inner loop to get `terminated`, because everytime the `column` value reaches the dead-end, you are `resetting` it to `0`, and hence the terminating condition of inner loop `(column < size)` will always be true, and also you are increasing the `row` value continuously, which will gradually result `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

Just remove that `if` condition. It is not needed.

Comment: Well that solves the error, however it still doesn't output in the formatted way that I wanted.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println()` as the last line in your `outer loop` to move to the next line.

Comment: @RohitJain Always quick to answer questions, nice job! Glad to constantly see your name in the java questions +1

Comment: @WilliamShatner.. haha :) Thanks. Trust me, I have increased my knowledge level by at least 30% from the time I joined SO.

Comment: Haha, your answers are always good, but you use backticks a little too much. `terminated`? `resetting`?

Comment: @durron597.. OOPs. I guess I should minimize their use now. I just try to highlight the keywords.